# LWJGL .Sys calss does not exist

Tags: java, lwjgl

I downloaded lwjgl and did required operations. But top of  "hello world" example it has "**import org.lwjgl.Sys;"** which does not exist.
And also

```
// System.out.println("Hello LWJGL " + Sys.getVersion() + "!");
//The line above, of course does not working so I removed.

//Get the resolution of the primary monitor
        GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        // Center our window
        glfwSetWindowPos(
            window,
            (vidmode.width() - WIDTH) / 2,    //IT WAS .getWidth()
            (vidmode.height() - HEIGHT) / 2  //IT WAS .getHeight()
        );
```

**

If I do these changes it works without it. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*org.lwjgl.Sys* only exists within pre 3.0.0 lwjgl versions. If you are using a higher version Sys will not be included. A replacement for the Sys class in the 3.0.0 would be in the class org.lwjgl.glfw. Here is a [link](https://www.lwjgl.org/guide) to a guide on how to use the class.

Comment: I am very thankful.So  replaced code will be System.out.println("Hello LWJGL " + GLFW.glfwGetVersionString() + "!");

Comment: Actually, glfwGetVersionString returns the GLFW version. To get the LWJGL version you have to use `Version.getVersion()`.